# How can i keep a file selected from input type="file"

Tags: java-ee-6, jakarta-ee

I have a small web application witch contains a button witch declared in HTML like that
`<input type="file" name ="b1" value="browse">` I would use any file selected from the descktop how i can keeped the name of this file and the file a lot to write her contains into TextArea and thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add `id` to your `<input>`:

```
<input type="file" name ="b1" id="b1" value="browse">
```

In `<head>`:

```
<script>
var file_name = document.getElementById("b1").value;
//file_name is your file
</script>
```